# How to add some text in textarea in Zend_Form?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, textarea

How put information in the textarea tag in Zend_Form? For example:

```
<textarea name="descNews" id="descNews" rows="5" class="txt_meta" cols="80">This is text!</textarea>
```

Zend form:

```
$description = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('descNews');
    $description->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->setAttribs(array(
                'rows'        => '5',
                'class'       => 'txt_meta'
        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `setValue(mixed $value)`

```
$description = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('descNews');

    $description->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->setAttribs(array(
                'rows'        => '5',
                'class'       => 'txt_meta'
        ));

$description->setValue('set your default vallue');
```

Or you can see on [zend doc](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8543)

hope it will work for you.